# ¿Cómo normalizar el contenido de una matriz que se encuentra en un archivo txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

¿Cómo hago para normalizar el contenido de una matriz?
He aplicado el siguiente código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data=pd.read_csv('matriz.txt',header=1,delim_whitespace=True)
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
dfs=normalize(data,axis=0,norm="max")
```

este es el contenido de matriz.txt:

```
carga                          posicion
-1907,64368327896              0,00000000000
-1837,39223105174              0,01741273261
-1696,36408581261               0,06147204306
-1541,86454926361                 0,10868110739
-1420,20896667520                  0,15785246496
-1274,32440011090              0,21273399758
-1026,77200413398             0,29832991759
-767,24156508194             0,42684021402
-466,67018352329             0,57492888126
-175,59776009596            0,72938611054
108,12377328260            0,90523214103
428,82152553734                 1,11148908242
801,08033207679                1,35600803960
1175,60246306842                1,63829757054
1554,83607888089                1,93286986181
1960,59682831716                2,22884388967
2378,62282214488               2,52855148177
2809,27139236284                2,83569535969
3263,19815965902                 3,16205967770
3689,46332739113                3,52969392718
3898,73942758306               4,02315085170
3963,28226513050                4,74165696716
4009,88741885059                 5,71171991204
4045,04100741374                5,71171991204
3881,99640177727                  6,90323789726
3624,88806962117                  8,21939187747
3471,25257249604                 9,54897062405
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-14296e1fec31> in <module>()
      6 data=pd.read_csv('matriz.txt',header=1,delim_whitespace=True)
      7 df=pd.DataFrame(data)
----> 8 dfs=normalize(data,axis=0,norm="max")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in normalize(X, norm, axis, copy, return_norm)
   1410 
   1411     X = check_array(X, sparse_format, copy=copy,
-> 1412                     estimator='the normalize function', dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
   1413     if axis == 0:
   1414         X = X.T

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    431                                       force_all_finite)
    432     else:
--> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    434 
    435         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '9,54897062405'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que se usa como separador decimal la coma (*1,13*) y no el punto (*1.13*) que es la sintaxis que usa Python. Pandas al parsear el archivo no realiza por tanto la conversión a `float` y el DataFrame tiene dos columnas de tipo `object` (objetos `str` Python):

```
>>> df.dtypes
carga       object
posicion    object
dtype: object
```

No obstante Pandas puede parsear esto sin problema usando el argumento `decimal` de [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
>>> data = pd.read_csv('matriz.txt', header=0, delim_whitespace=True, decimal=",")

>>> df.dtypes
carga       float64
posicion    float64
dtype: object
```

> **Nota:** Ten en cuenta que los índices en Python son base 0, `header=1` toma la segunda fila del csv como header (lo cual no se si es lo deseado), no la primera.

Comment: gracias lo eh agregado al código, lo eh probado y ha funcionado mil gracias!

Comment: gracias por la corrección del header no me habia percatado!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
gracias lo eh agregado al código, lo eh probado y ha funcionado mil gracias! – 
 este es el resultado de la normalizacion


[[-0.45423328  0.00182352]
[-0.41936882  0.00643756]
[-0.38117402  0.01138145]
[-0.35109878  0.01653084]
[-0.31503374  0.02227821]
[-0.25383476  0.0312421 ]
[-0.18967461  0.04470013]
[-0.11536847  0.06020847]
[-0.04341063  0.07638374]
[ 0.02672996  0.09479892]
[ 0.10601166  0.11639884]
[ 0.1980401   0.14200568]
[ 0.29062807  0.17156798]
[ 0.3843808   0.20241657]
[ 0.48469146  0.23341195]
[ 0.58803429  0.26479833]
[ 0.69449763  0.29696346]
[ 0.80671572  0.33114142]
[ 0.91209541  0.3696413 ]
[ 0.96383187  0.42131775]
[ 0.97978791  0.49656211]
[ 0.99130946  0.59815033]
[ 1.          0.59815033]
[ 0.95969272  0.72293006]
[ 0.89613135  0.86076209]
[ 0.85815016  1.        ]]
```

gracias por la corrección del header no me habia percatado!! :)